# jquery box-alignment

Tags: jquery, css

I have a (hopefuly) simpley question.. I have created a grid view of images. and i want it to pop up, and show a bigger image of the image u have click'd on.

but its made simply with float left. and jquery animate height/width. but sometimes there is a blank place, and i want it to be used aswell.

all my code should explain it :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .img{
        margin:5px;
        height:138px;
        width:138px;
        border:solid 1px red;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img').click(function(){

        $('.img').each(function(){
            $(this).animate({
            height: '138px',
            width: '138px'
            },200);
        });
        if($(this).width() > 139){
            $(this).animate({
            height: '138px',
            width: '138px'
        },200);
        }else{
            $(this).animate({
                height: '288px',
                width: '288px'
            },200);
        }
    });
});

</script>
<body>
    <div style="height:800px;width:600px;border:solid 1px green;overflow:auto;">

        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "all my code should explain it" it does not. Can you add a fiddle where the problem is visible?

Comment: You want a lightbox or Google-images style pop-up?

Comment: you don't need each function block anyway here.

Comment: if i click an box, i want it to scale up so it has the size of 2*2 boxes, and still dossen't switch line and not gonna make empty space. :).

Pop-up is a bad word to use here. its more like a "make the box bigger"

Comment: if just i could get the last box in the line to be in the line, and not jump down, it would be extreamly helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, it will animate in place, but it covers the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/RLxD7/1/

```
$('.img').click(function(){

    if($(this).width() > 139){
        $(this).animate({
        height: '138px',
        width: '138px',
            margin: '5px'
    },200);
    }else{
        $(this).animate({
            height: '288px',
            width: '288px',
            margin: '5px -145px -150px 5px',
            zIndex: '9999'
        },200);
    }
});
```

Edit: updated link.

Comment: it looks good.. but i just want the other to get push'd and not coverd :/